# Quick searching of today's email using Powershell and EWS

Tags: email, powershell, exchangewebservices

I'm pretty new to using EWS for retrieving e-mails from the exchange server. I would like to retrieve all the e-mails that have been sent to me today in the fastest way possible.

I'm a bit confused about `ItemView`. In **Code 1** are all the e-mails in the mailbox collected and then the search filter applied? In **Code 2** the mails are first ordered and then only the newest ones are returned?

Which solution would be the fastest to only retrieve the e-mails of today, even when the mailbox might get really full?

**Code 1:**

```
$Inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($Exchservice,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)

$PropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$PropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text;
$SearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsGreaterThan([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::DateTimeReceived,[system.DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1))

$View =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(100) 
$Mails = 0

do {
    $Mails = $ExchService.FindItems($Inbox.Id,$SearchFilter,$View)
    $ExchService.LoadPropertiesForItems($Mails,$PropertySet) | Out-Null

    foreach ($Mail in $Mails.Items) {
        "Received    : " + $Mail.DateTimeReceived  
        "Subject     : " + $Mail.Subject  
        "Body        : " + $Mail.Body
    }

    $View.Offset += $Mails.Items.Count
} while($Mails.MoreAvailable -eq $true)
```

**Code 2:**

```
$Properties.add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::DateTimeReceived)
$Properties.add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject)
$Properties.add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::Body)

$View = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(50,0,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OffsetBasePoint]::Beginning)
$View.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemTraversal]::Shallow
$View.PropertySet=$Properties
$View.OrderBy.add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::DateTimeReceived,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SortDirection]::Ascending)
```

Comment: Have you tried? Depending on the size of the mailbox, I'd expect different results. My experience is that applying a SearchFilter works better if your Exchange server can handle it.

Comment: It's difficult for me to try it out, as I don't have a lot of e-mails older than today. I was hoping someone with experience with this might shed some light on this.

Comment: The fastest way would probably be to create a search folder. http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2011/09/create-search-folder-using-ews-managed.html

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc535025(EXCHG.80).aspx) this has an impact on the exchange server and slows things down on every e-mail operation (move..). So I don't think it's the desirable solution. Is **Code 1** only slow when there are over 100 mails generated today? Or also when the mailbox contains over 100 mails in total?

Comment: Totally depends on the number of items in your view. You limit the Search View to 100, so the impact is limited. You can further optimize the search by setting the `PropertySet` on the view, before calling `FindItems`. Loading large properties (such as `Body`) has a much bigger impact I suspect.

Comment: I've updated **Code 1** with my `PropertySet`. I've tried to do what you said but I don't really understand it. Can you give me an example? The `Body` part is important for me..